# How can I install python3-dev locally?

Tags: python, python3, anaconda

I installed anaconda3 locally and I want to install python3-dev. How can I install python3-dev from source locally without root permission？

Answer (score 4):

If you use Anaconda, your python3-dev equivalent is already installed in `$CONDA_PREFIX/lib/pythonX.Y` where `X.Y` is the python version (example, 3.6).

Comment: $CONDA_PREFIX is not defined in my local installation.  Help?

Comment: You need to activate first your conda environment to use $CONDA_PREFIX variable. If you need to use python libs, compile inside ypur environment with Anaconda Compilers (they have correctly setup of path).